# U-Sql Create table statement failing

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to create a U-sql table from two tables using Create table as select (CTA's) as below -

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tpch_query2_result;

CREATE TABLE tpch_query2_result 
(
  INDEX idx_query2
  CLUSTERED(P_PARTKEY ASC)
  DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(P_PARTKEY)
) AS
  SELECT 
a.P_PARTKEY
  FROM part AS a INNER JOIN partsupp AS b ON a.P_PARTKEY == b.PS_PARTKEY;
```

But while running the U-sql query im getting the below error -

```
E_CSC_USER_QUALIFIEDCOLUMNNOTFOUND: Column 'P_PARTKEY' not found in rowset 'a'.
Line 11
E_CSC_USER_QUALIFIEDCOLUMNNOTFOUND: Column 'PS_PARTKEY' not found in rowset 'b'.
```

Not sure about the error. Can someone provide some insights on this error.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error normally indicates that the specified column does not exists in the specified rowset referenced by `a` (i.e., `part`) or `b` (i.e., `partsupp`). What is the schema of either of these tables? do they have columns of the expected names?

Comment: Yes Michael..both these columns exist in part and partsupp rowset

Comment: hi Michael..attached the table creation and insert scripts in the next comments

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS part 
(p_partkey int, p_name string, p_mfgr string, p_brand string, p_type string, p_size int, p_container string, p_retailprice double, p_comment string,INDEX idx_part CLUSTERED (p_partkey)
DISTRIBUTED BY HASH (p_partkey)) ;

Comment: DECLARE DataFilePath string = "/benchmark/part.tbl";
part = EXTRACT partkey int, p_name string, mfgr string, brand string, p_type string, size int, container string, retailprice double, comment string FROM DataFilePath
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter: '|', encoding:Encoding.UTF8);

INSERT INTO part SELECT * FROM part;

Comment: Note - Removed the "@" symbol from Declare, part and select  * from part